# Properties of a Matrix that diagonalizes another matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

P = (0 1 2;2 0 3;3 4 0) is a matrix that diagonalizes another matrix A.

Does the matrix (3 4 0;2 0 3;0 1 2) diagonlize A? When i swap the top row and bottom row with each other, Will this matrix still be able to diagonalize A?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, no. Asserting that $P$ diagonalizes $A$, that is, asserting that $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix is equivalent to asserting that the columns of $P$ are eigenvectors of $A$ (and that $P$ is invertible). In general, if you swap the rows like that, you will not have eigenvectors anymore.